# Either my session isn't setting properly or my mysql is incorrect. Can someone kindly tell me which?

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I am building my first login for my bands webpage.  After three weeks of toil it looks right to me but clearly isn't.  Every tutorial I have studied selects a user form many users.  My site only has one user so I have come up with what I believe to be a straight to the point piece of code.

When I run it, it gives me the 'you screwed up' error message.  I have tried putting the username and pass directly into variable without the the mysql statements but I still get the same error.

When run it should set a session and then redirect to my GUI page.  The GUI page works fine but as the session is not set, it immediately redirects back to the login page.

I am not getting any database connection errors.

This is my login script. I am not concerned right now about security.  I just want it to work.  Help me stackOverflow, you are my only hope.! (lame star wars reference)

if (isset($_POST ['submit'])){

```
  $username = $_POST ['name'];
  $password = $_POST ['password'];

if(!empty($username) && !empty($password)){

     $UserQuery = ("SELECT `username` FROM `logindeets` WHERE 1");  
     $PassQuery = ("SELECT `password` FROM `logindeets` WHERE 1");

     $dbUser = mysql_query($UserQuery);
     $dbPass = mysql_query($PassQuery);

    if($username == $dbUser && $password == $dbPass){ 

              $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
              header("location:gui.php");
              }
              else{
                    echo '<script language="javascript">';
                    echo 'alert("You screwed up")';
                    echo '</script>';
                   }
                }
                else{
                     echo '<script language="javascript">';
                     echo 'alert("Please fill in all of the required fields")';
                     echo '</script>';
                    }
             }
```

?>

Comment: mysql_query doesn't return what you think.

Comment: Why are you executing two queries anyway? `SELECT \`username\`,\`password\` FROM \`logindeets\` WHERE 1` And you do realise that this will get every entry in your logindeets table? Not simply the user who is trying to login

Comment: But please start learning to use prepared statements/bind vars with MySQLi or PDO, rather than the old deprecated MySQL extension

Comment: I have never heard of PDO..

Comment: So there is a proper way of getting to pieces of data from mySQL into two separate variables?  The tutrorials I have studied are a bit old.

Comment: I'm reading the PDO manual now.  Thanks!

Comment: So I don't need to get the username and password from the db, I just need to check if they match the ones on the db. Is that right?

Comment: Well if you want to use a more secure password using password_hash() rather than storing it as plaintext in your database as you are now, then you do need to retrieve the password from the database

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now. The problem was my logic.  I thought I needed to store the passwords in variables where all I had to do was check if matching data existed on the database.  I still cannot set my sessions properly yet, but one thing at a time. Thank you all.